# is it possible to run a django app in a simple hosting?

Tags: django, hosting

Hello friends I have one question about django and hostings, is It possible to run a django app in a simple hosting with python support or you must to use a VPS? 
I know that php framework like codeigniter,symfony... run in any hosting with php support but I know that django it´s a little special.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are Platform as a Service few hosting providers out there.

- [Python Anywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/)
- [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/)
- [OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com/)

But you cant get it from cPanel like in PHP. Each of them have a very good doccumentation on hosting in their platform. Check them out.